# Can't Reuse Featured Image?

Tags: wordpress, image, reusability, wordpress-featured-image

Ok I am using a featured image(F image) for each post on the main/front page. It works for the most part but on posts featuring videos, I want to reuse the same F image each time.

For some reason, the F image will work fine when it is first uploaded, but when I try to reuse the same image in another post, the space where it should appear on the home page is blank even though there were no errors reported. I've tried linking by url AND by selecting the desired image from the media admin page.

The only way it works is by uploading a completely a whole new instance of the same image. That is moronic. There has to be some way to reuse an image without reuploading it for every single post I need to use it on. I'm nauseous at the thought of 54 instances of the same image being present on my server. What gives? Am I just being noobilicous and overlooked the relevant php code? Thanks for all of your input!

Here is the code from php functions:

```
<?php
// Make theme available for translation
// Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
load_theme_textdomain( 'your-theme', TEMPLATEPATH . '/languages' );

$locale = get_locale();
$locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH . "/languages/$locale.php";
if ( is_readable($locale_file) )
    require_once($locale_file);

// Get the page number
function get_page_number() {
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        print ' | ' . __( 'Page ' , 'your-theme') . get_query_var('paged');
    }
} // end get_page_number
// Enable post thumbnails
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(300, 200, true);
?>
```

Here is how it is called in the index.php:

```
<!-- get the thumbnail -->
<?php
//Get images attached to the post
$img = null;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'numberposts' => -1,
'order' => 'ASC',
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
$img = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID );
break;
} ?>

<!-- ***** THE ACTUAL IMAGE ***** -->
<span class="the-thumbnail">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
  </a>
</span>
<!-- ***** END THE ACTUAL IMAGE ***** -->

<?php }
?>
<!-- end get the thumbnail -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your

```
<span class="the-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
    </a>
</span>
```

to

```
<span class="the-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: I was so prepared to tell you how awesome you are, unfortunately your suggestion didn't resolve the issue. Even so, I don't doubt your overall awesomeness and welcome any other ideas.